# Angular 2 - ContentEditable 2 way binding - Updates after second onBlur() event

Tags: data-binding, angular, contenteditable, onblur

I have a table that has price, quantity and total.  I added a 'contenteditable' attribute to the price and quantity fields and I want it to automatically update the 'total' field when either price or quantity has changed. (I am using a modified contenteditable component from [this](https://www.namekdev.net/2016/01/two-way-binding-to-contenteditable-element-in-angular-2/) post)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td (blur)='edit()' contenteditable='true' [(contenteditableModel)]='price'>{{price}}</td>
        <td (blur)='edit()' contenteditable='true' [(contenteditableModel)]='quantity'>{{quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{total}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my app.ts, I have an edit() function defined that does the calculation.

```
  edit() {
    this.total = this.price * this.quantity;
  }
```

However, total doesn't update until the onBlur is executed a second time. Why is that?

Here is a plunker link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/1cxQLXZTRmCTPCdFUUk6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your blur handler on the parent component is executed earlier than the handler within `ContenteditableModel` directive.

You need to update the total after executing child handler:

```
 <td [contenteditableModel]="price" 
     (contenteditableModelChange)="price = $event; updateTotal()"
     contenteditable="true">{{price}}</td>
 <td [contenteditableModel]="quantity"
     (contenteditableModelChange)="quantity = $event; updateTotal()" 
     contenteditable="true">{{quantity}}</td>
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hcg9YwtBdVKPpEBH5Xg9?p=preview)**